# How to fetch from a table has lots of foreign keys to an another table..?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called USER and it has a column "id" and "username",
And have another table called BUGS and it has a columns "createdBy", "updatedBy" and these columns is a foreign key to the "id" column in USER.
So how can i join twice from USER.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT
  u1.user_name AS created_by_name
  u2.user_name AS updated_by_name
  b.id         AS bug_id
FROM
  bugs       b
  JOIN users u1 ON b.created_by = u1.id
  JOIN users u2 ON b.updated_by = u2.id
```

If the `updated_by` column can be null then you want a `LEFT JOIN` for that.